# Can someone solve my query regarding CPTPlotDatasource in corePlot

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, core-plot

Here *CPTScatterPlotFiledX* shows error as:

> Binary Operator cannot be applied to operand of Type
>   _CPTScatterPlotFiledX and UInt!

and same for CPTScatterPlotFiledY

```
func numberForPlot(plot: CPTPlot!, field fieldEnum: UInt, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> NSNumber! {
    switch fieldEnum
    {
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX :
        if plot.identifier .isEqual("aapl")
        {
            var num: NSNumber = aaplArray.objectAtIndex(Int(idx)).valueForKey("x") as! NSNumber
            return num
            break
        }
        else if plot.identifier .isEqual("goog")
        {
            var num: NSNumber = googArray.objectAtIndex(Int(idx)).valueForKey("x") as! NSNumber
            return num
            break
        }
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY :
        if plot.identifier .isEqual("aapl")
        {
            var num: NSNumber = aaplArray.objectAtIndex(Int(idx)).valueForKey("y") as! NSNumber
            return num
            break
        }
        else if plot.identifier .isEqual("goog")
        {
            var num: NSNumber = googArray.objectAtIndex(Int(idx)).valueForKey("y") as! NSNumber
            return num
            break
        }
    }
    return NSNumber(float: 0)
}
```

Comment: Please edit the formatting of your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `case CPTScatterPlotFieldX` with `case UInt(CPTScatterPlotField.X.rawValue)` in order to cast the `enum` type to a raw `UInt` value

Comment: Thanks a lot dear...:)

Comment: @AkshatRathore You're welcome :) If the answer solves your issue you can accept it in order to mark this question as resolved

Comment: i have one problem in graph.. how to disable scrolloing in y axis and negative side of graph (-x and  -y), i have not need it so how to remove it. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast the field parameter to a `CPTScatterPlotField`. This is how the Core Plot examples do it:

```
switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field))! {
case .X:
    return (oneDay * Double(recordIndex)) as NSNumber

case .Y:
    return self.plotData[Int(recordIndex)] as NSNumber
}
```

Comment: i have one problem in graph.. how to disable scrolloing in y axis and negative side of graph (-x and  -y), i have not need it so how to remove it. thanks..